# Compare current time with lambda expression in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, timespan

I want to using lambda expression to compare current DateTime.Now with time retrieved from database (time).

I try this:

```
string time = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00") + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00") + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("00");
TimeSpan _currentTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

IQueryable<user> Query = _context.user.Where(s => s.userShifts.Any(s2 => s2.DayOfWeekId == _todayNumber && _currentTime >= s2.TimeFrom && _currentTime <= s2.TimeTo));
```

I got the following error:

> {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

What's the wrong !!

Comment: That code won't compile: the first statement has two errors, to start with. Please provide an *actual* [mcve].

Comment: I update the example

Comment: why go through the trouble of parsing ? why not just do var _currentTIme= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay

Comment: Right, Thanks Danny for your help.

Comment: Note that given that your second line is where the exception was being thrown, you should have been able to tell that this has nothing to do with WPF or lambda expressions. Please really work on diagnostics before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TimeOfDay in place of parseExact

```
var _currentTime= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, This is the right way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok .. The right format is:

```
TimeSpan _currentTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "hh':'mm':'ss", null);
```

Hope this help.